# How to match specific length of occurrences in RegEx/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following variable:

```
var arg = '--test';
```

The value of `arg` can start with one or two hypens: `-` or `--`, but not more.

I want to handle that and I figured I should do RegEx with this problem.

So far, my code is:

```
if(arg.substr(0, 2).match(/-{1,2}/gi)) {
    // doing my stuff here...
}
```

What I do is slice first two characters of the string and try to test the hypen occourence in that sliced string, but RegEx is not my strong side so that's where I'm stuck.

Basically, I want to test if there's at least one or maximum two `-` hypens in the string/argument.

Comment: Maybe you just need [`if (/^-{1,2}(?!-)/.test(arg))`](https://regex101.com/r/hQ0lR7/1)?

Comment: Yes, it shortens up the condition, but again, I can pass `-----test`. I want to limit it only to 1 or 2 hypens.

Comment: Works now! Thanks. I didn't see you updated with `(?!-)`. Thank you.

Comment: The `(?!-)` will not allow 3 or more hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the number of hyphens with a `(?!-)` negative lookahead after `^-{1,2}`:

```
/^-{1,2}(?!-)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ0lR7/1)

Pattern breakdown:

- `^` - start of a string
- `-{1,2}` - one or two hyphens
- `(?!-)` - fail the match if there is a hyphen after 2 hyphens at the start.

**Note** that to check if a regex matches a given string or not in JS, you'd better use `RegExp#test()` method, see the demo below.

```js
function tst() {
  var arg = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (/^-{1,2}(?!-)/.test(arg)) {     // <======== Check if a string matches the pattern
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = arg + " matched"; 
  } else {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = arg + " failed to match"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input id="test" value="---test" placeholder="<Input a test string>"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="tst()" id="r"/>
 <div id="res"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/vH6kB3/1):

```
/^--?(?!-)/
```

How it works:

- `^` selects start of string
- `-` selects the first hyphen
- `-?` selects the optional second hyphen
- `(?!-)` fails if there is a third hyphen

To select `-` or `--`, you can use wither of:

- `--?` (`3` digits)
- `-{1,2}` (`6` digits)

I used the first method because it is shorter and easier to read